# object with id transformed to js variable in IE8 (WinXP)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

There is a strange behaviour I discovered using IE 8.0.6001 (latest version available for Win XP) :

with the following html code :

```
<div id="lifetime">blablabla</div>
```

And JS code :

```
lifetime = "whatever";
```

I get "Object doesn't support this property or method".
After some research, I've found that IE created a variable for every object having an id!

Is there a way to avoid this ... or will I have to check every variable name for that let say "annoying" browser?

Of course, the same code works perfect on other browsers (including IE9 on Win 7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I've found it...

IE8 creates variables for every object with an id. The way to avoid the problem is to follow the recommendations ;)

```
var lifetime = "whatever";
```

Will work!